# Performance of reference to property or getter from template in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a question regarding performance in Angular.
Is there a performance difference between referencing a public property and a getter defined in a component?

Example:
I have a template, and it references `isActivate` that is defined in a component like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isActivate">Do stuff...</div>
```

In the component:

```
export class TestComponent {
    public isActivate: boolean;
```

But it can have a getter instead:

```
public get isActivate(): boolean {
    return true;
}
```

In performance wise, which is better, and why?

Comment: It is not recommended to databind functions since they are called during every change detection cycle. Since a getter is a function, I think it will have a performance impact.

Comment: I'd agree to @Ploppy's point above but then the other day, I also read a post by Mosh Hamedani on LinkedIn that says the opposite:

https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6443150956254367745

According to it, it's just a fad and performance isn't really an issue in that case. But if it's not required, I'd suggest not to use them. They can be used as helpers in case you want to have access to some form controls in the template for showing some error messages for eg.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I'm not sure that linkedin post makes a great argument. If there are performance implications to something then it makes sense why folks generally avoid it because not everyone will be running performance tests for every situation, nor will they remember. For this situation, the getter is not a concern but avoiding functions in templates is definitely not just a fad as it's an easy rule that avoids some pitfalls

Comment: @r0m4n, yeah I mean I just added that as a reference. What I meant to convey is that it won't make much sense to write expensive logic inside a getter since it gets called on every change detection cycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On each Change detection Angular compare previous and current bound values. Performance difference between getter(i.e. function) vs property access is nothing till `function` do nothing. If we want to optimize that - [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the function by using [pure pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-pipes).

Another, more general, solution is create `apply` pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'apply',
})
export class ApplyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T, U extends any[]>(fn: (...fnArgs: U) => T, ...args: U): T {
    return fn(...args);
  }
}

// TS
foo = {};
computeSmth(foo){
  // some computation
  return 'result';
}

// HTML
{{ computeSmth | apply : foo}}
```

PS also we can use decorator to memoize getter function

Comment: Good point. But why would someone create a getter for an expensively computed value in the first place?

Comment: We want to keep our state normalized so all computation is moved from actions(imperative style) to getters (declarative style)

Comment: getter can access deep nested structure (more descriptive alias), groupBy values and much more, also getter can use another getter