# Angular pipe will not update the template

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I am creating an app in Angular and I am using a pure pipe 'async' to subscribe to an Observable inside a template like this:

```
<nav *ngIf="device.isDesktop$ | async as desktop" class="sidenav__wrapper">
  {{ desktop }}
  <div *ngFor="let item of menuItems" class="sidenav__item">
    <div class="sidenav__icon">
      <i [ngClass]="['gg-' + item.icon]"><span></span></i>
    </div>
    <span class="sidenav__item-name">{{ item.name }}</span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

However, the desktop value is not updating at all, even though when the values show up when i console.log like this:

```
  get isDesktop$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._deviceType$.asObservable().pipe(
      map((type) => type === Device.Desktop),
      tap(console.log)
    );
  }
```

Comment: So actually your question is "how should I set to recognize if it is Desktop or mobile"?

Comment: No, my question is why change detection does not run after the values are emitted

Answer (score 0):

yourcomponent.ts

```js
import {BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
export class YourComponent {
  public isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver
    .observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(map((result: BreakpointState) => {
      return result.matches;
    }));
  constructor (private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver){
}

}
```

yourcomponent.html

```js
<whateverTag *ngIf="(isHandset$ | async)"></whateverTag>
```

Comment: The values I emit in my isDesktop$ are irrelevant, they are emitted via BehaviorSubject and the values are correct (as I stated). The problem is that the template does not get updated. My question is why, even though I am using an async pipe

Comment: Just do I as pointed out and it will work everywhere. Only with the code you provided is not enough to figure it out. First of all, why use Getter? Using like so you will need `lastValueFrom` from `rxjs` which is async. So your getter should be `async`

Comment: I am using an observable, why should I have a promise to use async? I don't think we're on the same page here...

Comment: What I meant is using getter is somehow influencing the performance of the behavior you expect. Check here [Getter Vs Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353671/performance-of-reference-to-property-or-getter-from-template-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your code and it actually works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjo88g?file=src%2Fmain.ts

If you try it you will see that `desktop` value disappears every time you switch `isDesktop$`. It happens because of `*ngIf="device.isDesktop$ | async as desktop"` condition. When it's `false` the whole `nav` block gets hidden because of `ngIf`. That might cause the confusion.