# ngOnChanges in ChildComponent invoking getter contionously

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a ChildComponent which has ngOnChanges() and also makes a service call returns a Observable .

I have observed that the getters gets called continously when there is a small change in the mouse position.

In its simplest form below is the code for this. After the page gets loaded , if I keep a breakpoint inside Filter() and check() , I notice that it keeps hitting the breakpoint even for a small change in mouse position on screen .
check() is invoked in both html and .ts but Filter is invoked only in html file.

How do I prevent the contionous invocation of filter() and check() as I am aware that it could lead to memory leaks and screen being frozen

**ChildComponent.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges
{
 // Receives test1/test2 from Parent
  @Input() dataFromParent : string;
  valueFromService : any;
  
  get Filter(): string {
   switch(this.dataFromParent) {
     case 'test1' : return this.valueFromService['A']
     case 'test2' : return this.valueFromService['B']
     }
   }

   get check(): Array<string> {
       return ['test1','test2'];
   }
  
  constructor(private service: Service) {}
  
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
   // Check if dataFromParent has any of value in ('test1','test2') proceed to service call
   if(this.dataFromParent && this.check.includes(this.changes['dataFromParent'])
   {
     this.service.subscribe(result) => {
     this.valueFromService = result;
    }
   }
}
```

**ChildComponent.html**

```
<div *ngIf="dataFromParent && check.includes(dataFromParent)>
  {{ valueFromService}} {{Filter}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to this particular line: `<div *ngIf="dataFromParent && check.includes(dataFromParent)>`.

When you bind a function to the template, Angular doesn't know what the inputs are, so it re-evaluates the function output at every change detection. This is also the case of your getters, and this is why you see it the function running so often.
Angular provides [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353671/performance-of-reference-to-property-or-getter-from-template-in-angular) as a way to bind functions to the template, but you could use alternative solution in your case.
One example is [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (basically caching the output of the function) or trasforming the property into a subject paired with `async` pipe (here there is [an example](https://dev.to/hankchiutw/you-may-not-need-ngonchanges-40h6)).

If the function is simple it shouldn't affect performance though.